# How can I use Apache beam experimental features

Tags: redis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I see there is a RedisIO source and sink since Apache Beam 2.2.0, but it seems it is impossible to just use it.
Looking at the code, I see it is marked as [experimental](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.4.0/sdks/java/io/redis/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/redis/RedisIO.java#L108).
How can I still use it, even when such ?

Please advise,
Shushu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found I was missing a dependency...
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-io-redis/2.4.0

Answer (score 2):

For clarification, the `Experimental` annotation is simply a documentation feature to denote that the behavior of the class, method, etc may change. It doesn't have any implications or restrictions for ability to use. As you already discovered, you were just missing a dependency.

Just FYI, annotations are a feature of Java.

Reference:
1. [Java Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)
2. [Apache Beam Experimental Annotation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/annotations/Experimental.html)